# How to prevent browser from replacing email in text field with JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, email, spam-prevention

I have a field in a form like so:

```
<input type="text" name="email" />
```

I'm using PHP to check the validity of the form, which contains other fields in addition to this one.  If the validity check fails, I store the values in the session and output the form again with an error message and the form values prepopulated.

If I add an email, say "person@example.com", and the form invalidates, then "person@example.com" gets replaced with JS:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'> <!-- var prefix = 'ma' + 'il' + 'to'; var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '='; var addy34269 = 'person' + '@'; addy34269 = addy34269 + 'example' + '.' + 'com'; document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy34269 + '\'>'); document.write(addy34269); document.write('<\/a>'); //-->\n </script><script type='text/javascript'> <!-- document.write('<span style=\'display: none;\'>'); //--> </script>This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it. <script type='text/javascript'> <!-- document.write('</'); document.write('span>'); //--> </script>
```

Needless to say this is not what I want.  This happens in Chrome and Firefox; I'm not sure about the others.  How can I prevent the browser from replacing the email after form invalidation?

I had thought of using str_replace to make the email not look like an email, then use JS to do another string replacement to bring it back to its original value, but I'd like to do this without JS if possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not do it without js? Seems like you're already warning you're users that javascript is required...

Comment: This is not my JS, this is the browser's.

Comment: Do you have a link to a test page or the validation code that you use?

Comment: The browser is not doing this, something on your page is doing it [either host or another script]

Comment: Sure they do.  They are programmed partly in it aren't they

Comment: Are you using Joomla, by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you (or your host) is using Joomla! you can disable the "Email cloaking" Plugin completly or disable the cloaking feature for a single email as discussed [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2002965)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before. I use CloudFare on my sites and email address in plaintext are encoded to prevent them from being stolen by spambots. You might have a similar service which helps protect your web host.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'> <!-- var prefix = 'ma' + 'il' + 'to'; var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '='; var addy34269 = 'person' + '@'; addy34269 = addy34269 + 'example' + '.' + 'com'; document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy34269 + '\'>'); document.write(addy34269); document.write('<\/a>'); //-->\n </script><script type='text/javascript'> <!-- document.write('<span style=\'display: none;\'>'); //--> </script>This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it. <script type='text/javascript'> <!-- document.write('</'); document.write('span>'); //--> </script>
```

Read through the code carefully and you will notice how it states "This email address is being protected from spambots."

EDIT: This is a server side edit so every browser that requests the page will get that result.

Comment: It is not a server-side edit.  I have a print_r on my session showing the email exactly how it should be

Comment: @moonDogDog yes this is usually all processed after the PHP is processed. Your host should be able to tell you what the software is on the server. Also if that JS is what you see in your source then it is either the programmer or the web server.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have cloudflare activated as you CDN with the highest security settings. You can log into your cloudflare account and change your setting to moderate.

Also if you are using joomla, you can add {emailcloak=off} in front of the email address that is being replaced. For example: {emailcloak=off} youremail@emailofyoursite.com

This usually fixes the issue.